# Custom Ribbon Button doesn't show on subsites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon, custom-action

I've successfully added a custom ribbon button to my site and everything shows up as expected. However, when I go to a sub site, my custom ribbon button doesn't show up. How can I get my button to show up in the main site and also sub sites? I assumed that a button deployed to the main site would also carry over to sub sites but I guess that isn't the case. Anyone have any ideas or guidance? My button get's added to the "Media" group of the "Insert" tab for the RTE.

Oh, and I am deploying this with a "Site" scoped feature.

Here is my button code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Id="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditingTools.MyCompany_InsertVideoButton"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                    Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls._children">
                    <Button
                        Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Controls.MyCompany_InsertVideoButton"
                        ToolTipTitle="Video"
                        ToolTipDescription="Insert a video into the page."
                        Sequence="50"
                        LabelText="Insert Video"
                        Image16by16="/_layouts/MyCompany/images/icons/ribbonInsertVideoButton_16.png"
                        Image32by32="/_layouts/MyCompany/images/icons/ribbonInsertVideoButton_32.png"
                        Command="MyCompany_InsertVideoButtonCommand"
                        TemplateAlias="o1" />
                </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler
                        Command="MyCompany_InsertVideoButtonCommand"
                        CommandAction="javascript:alert('MyCompanyInsertVideoButton clicked!');"
                />
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Oh, and I am deploying this with a "Site" scoped feature.

I believe this is your problem. You are getting the activation on the current site, but because it is deployed with `Site` scope, the feature will need to be explicitly activated for **every** site and subsite you want to use it with.

If you want it to automatically apply to all sites/subsites within a particular web application, deploy your solution with a `WebApplication` scoped feature. To activate it once deployed, go to *Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Web Applications*, then choose "Manage Features" in the Web Applications ribbon.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken in my understanding of SharePoint, a "Site" feature is deployed to the entire "Site Collection", thus this should affect sub sites as well. We "Web" scoped feature would be for just a single web site and thus wouldn't affect sub sites. I'm not sure a web application scoped feature would even allow me to change the Ribbon for the sites within that web app. But I guess it couldn't hurt to try it. I'm almost thinking I'll just add it at runtime via my master page, but that just seems like it might add unnecessary overhead for something I should be able to do with the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. There might be an issue, if you are deploying the ribbon button feature as a farm solution. Can you try the same as a sandbox solution deployment? That might work.

Comment: I can't use a sandbox solution though since I'm using other things in my feature that need to be deployed as a farm solution. Maybe I'll need to try it though to see if it works and then separate out just this part into a different feature.